# i've done a mistake with SDDL and now i can't access a service

Tags: active-directory, service

I had a task to allow some non-admin user to restart a service.
I've used the SDDL way in order to allow him the restart, the problem is, that i mistakenly added only the new SDDL without the whole permissions it had and now i've lost all control on the service apart from the non-admin user which is able to restart it.
When i open the services.msc window i cannot find the service but i know it's running as the application which uses this service keeps working as it should, but it seems like the service is hidden.
Is there any way to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance
Itai

Comment: if you look at the current sddl who has ownership?

Comment: only the non-admin user which has RPWP (stop/start)

Comment: as admin you can take ownership then reset the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony - after overriding the acl's of the service no user had any admin access to the service, the only access i had was with the non-admin user and he could only stop/start the service.

Solution:
I deleted the service settings from the registry and then i was able to re-install the service, now it works as it should.

Comment: darn that was to easy...